# how to calculate sum of column values by removing duplicate id's using PHP in excel sheet?

Tags: php, mysqli

No i am calculating total balance amt ($row['Bal‌​anceAmt']).In this one more field is there Invoice No .Invoice numbers will be duplicates .If duplicates comes only calculate balance at once.For example invoice number are 1,1,2,3,4,4,7 and balance amt are 10,10,30,40,20,20,80 and total balance should be 20+30+20+80=15
Now the problem is calculating all the balance amount includes all the duplicate invoice numbers also
is there any option to remove this error?

```
 $sql = "SELECT a.cusName as CustomerName, a.invoiceNo as InvoiceNo,
                a.bal_amt as BalanceAmt,
                b.itemsName as Items,b.rate as Rate,
                ROUND(b.amt_vat + b.amount, 2) as Amount
                FROM invoices a, invoice_items b where a.invoiceID=b.invoiceid and a.status IS NULL
                and a.invoiceDate between '$getfromdate' and '$gettodate' 
                order by a.invoiceID desc";

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
  $resultpaymenttotal = mysqli_query($link, $sqlgettotalpyment);


  // Header info settings
  header("Content-Type: application/xls");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$xls_filename");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: 0");

  /***** Start of Formatting for Excel *****/
  // Define separator (defines columns in excel &amp; tabs in word)
  $sep = "\t"; // tabbed character
    $col_cnt = 0;
  // Start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields
  for ($i = 0; $i<mysqli_num_fields($result); $i++) {
    $field_info = mysqli_fetch_field($result);
    $col = "{$field_info->name}";
    echo $col . "\t";
     $col_cnt++;
  }
  print("\n");
  // End of printing column names

  // Start while loop to get data
  $row_cnt = 0;
  $tot_BalanceAmt = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $schema_insert = "";
    $schema_insert .= $row['CustomerName'].$sep.$row['CustomerMob'].$sep.$row['InvoiceNo'].$sep.$row['AdvanceAmt'].$sep.$row['BalanceAmt'].$sep.$row['Items'].$sep.$row['Rate'].$sep.$row['Amount'];
    $tot_BalanceAmt += $row['BalanceAmt'];
    $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
    $schema_insert .= "\t";
    print(trim($schema_insert));
    print "\n";
    $row_cnt ++;
  }
  print "\n";

  $schema_insert = "";
  for($i=0;$i<$col_cnt-25;$i++)
  {
    $schema_insert .= " ".$sep;
  }
  $schema_insert .= "TOTAL BALANCE = ".$sep;
  $schema_insert .= $tot_BalanceAmt.$sep;
  $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
  $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
  $schema_insert .= "\t";
  print($schema_insert);
  print "\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Right after initialization `$tot_BalanceAmt = 0;` add `$invoiceHasProcessed = array();`
2. Into body of *while-loop* string of code:

`$tot_BalanceAmt += $row['BalanceAmt'];`

replace with

```
if (!in_array($row['InvoiceNo'], $invoiceHasProcessed)) {
    $tot_BalanceAmt += $row['BalanceAmt'];
    $invoiceHasProcessed[] = $row['InvoiceNo'];
}
```